# PHP changing image pixel colors also changes nearby pixels

Tags: php, image-processing

I'm working on a project in PHP where I am manipulating image pixels. I can do this fine, however I am not trying to change every pixel. I am only intending to change roughly half of the pixels, and only slightly (+- 10 or less in red in rgb color). The issue I am having is that after the image has been manipulated and exported to a .jpg file, I notice that the color changes blend together. That is to say, when I change the color of a pixel, it also changes the color of nearby pixels slightly.

This is not behavior I want, since half the pixels should not see any sort of color change. Is there any way to work around this?

More information:

I am manipulating JPEG images.

I am using imagecolorallocate() and imagesetpixel() to change each individual pixels an appropriate amount. I notice that if I examine each pixel of the image resource BEFORE exporting the image to a file, everything is exactly as it should be. Only pixels I intend to change have a different value from before, and there is no "blending" of pixels.

However, after I call imagejpeg() on the altered image resource, the "blending" of colors occurs. This is something I would very much like to avoid, since it defeats the entire purpose of me adjusting the color of some pixels but not others.

The is how I am changing each pixel

```
for ($x = 0; $x < strlen($msglenBin); $x++){
            colorAdjust($img,$x,0,$msglenBin[$x]);
            var_dump(imagecolorat($img, $x, 0),imagecolorsforindex($img, imagecolorat($img, $x, 0)));
        }
```

The colorAdjust function:

```
function colorAdjust($img,$x,$y,$value){
        if ($value == '1'){
            $rgb = imagecolorat($img, $x, $y);
            $r = ($rgb >> 16) & 0xFF;
            $g = ($rgb >> 8) & 0xFF;
            $b = $rgb & 0xFF;
            $r = $r - 15;
            if ($r >=255){
                $r=245;
            }
            $to=imagecolorallocate($img, $r, $g, $b);
            imagesetpixel($img,$x,$y,$to);
        }else{
        }
    }
```

And this is how I am exporting it to file:

```
imagejpeg($newImage,"images/encryptedimage.jpg",150)
```

To reiterate my problem. My project requires that only some pixels in an image be changed in color, and only very slightly. All the other pixels should not see ANY change in color. However, when I do change the color of a pixel, "blending" occurs that changes the color of nearby pixels. This inadvertently causes some pixels that should stay 100% the same color to change.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you are using a wrong parameter for "quality" when saving the JPEG images.

You are using `imagejpeg($newImage,"images/encryptedimage.jpg",150)` with 150 as quality, but this value [is only defined from 0 to 100](http://php.net/imagejpeg) with 75 being the default.

Second thing: The way JPEG is getting huge compression rates is exactly by mixing pixels together. You cannot expect to only change single pixels and keep them after compressing to JPEG. [Read about it](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JPEG).

One can only speculate what happens in your code or in the imagejpeg function, but maybe your quality is too high, resulting in an integer overflow, applying a much lower quality than intended, with pixels bleeding into each other.

Set a correct quality value. Then try again. Remember that having "quality=100" is identical to getting huge images - probably not desirable. You could also switch image formats: PNG will be able to preserve 24bit color and single pixel changes, but the amount of data will also increase.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I'll read up about the JPEG files. I honestly just used it because that was the handy image that was lying around and didn't think twice about it. I'll try everything with PNG images and see if the problem solves itself. Changing the quality to 100 did not solve the problem.

Comment: Using PNG images did in fact solve the problem. Thank you!